# Problems with autoref and phantomsubcaption

Tags: hyperref, subfloats, subcaption, links

I have a figure that already has the subcaption. I'm using `hyperref` and `subcaption` package for this.

I have something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\autoref{Fig1a}, \autoref{Fig1b}, \autoref{Fig1c} and \autoref{Fig1d} are in \autoref{Fig1}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
{
\includegraphics{example-image}
\phantomsubcaption\label{Fig1a}
\phantomsubcaption\label{Fig1b}
\phantomsubcaption\label{Fig1c}
\phantomsubcaption\label{Fig1d}
}
\caption{Image description:
\textbf{(a)}~figure 1a,
\textbf{(b)}~figure 1b,
\textbf{(c)}~figure 1c and
\textbf{(d)}~figure 1d
}
\label{Fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It works perfectly when I compile. However, other document with the same structure, I don't know why instead of **Figure 1a**, **Figure 1b**.... I'm getting **item 1a**, **item 1b**

Any help?

Comment: Why are you showing us a document that works though? '*Other document with the same structure,... I'm getting item 1a, item 1b* ', Why not create a minimal document that shows this instead? Anyway, would the `cleveref` package be an acceptable alternative?

Comment: @Troy I tryed to reproduce the error, but the error is occoring only in that especific document. It's to long to show, besides have some confidential information

Comment: @DanielValencia: Check the placement of the `\label` commands

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Where should I place it?

Comment: @DanielValencia: Inside the correct environment. Your actual document says `item` instead of `figure`, this looks like if the labels have been used inside of an `enumerate` instead of `figure` environment

Comment: \label should be placed as close as possible after \caption.